# Dr.Memory crashes when trying to profile any c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, dr-memory

I've recently installed Windows 10 and with it I've installed VS2015 community edition with update 1 (the exact version is 14.0.24720.00).

After installing [Dr.Memory](http://drmemory.org/) tool I've tried to use it one one of my programs but it crashed.

I've written a new project (Win32 Console application, empty project, no sdl) with simple program that literary does nothing :

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
};

int main() {

    //A *a = new A();

}
```

And it crashed with the same symptoms:

```
C:\some_path>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin\drmemory.exe" -- drmem.exe
~~Dr.M~~ Dr. Memory version 1.9.0
~~Dr.M~~ Running "drmem.exe"
~~Dr.M~~ WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000005
```

Comment: It is always a good test to see if you want to invest time in learning to use a tool.  If you get an insta-crash like this then you know to keep shopping.  Whether you want to invest the time in the open source project to repair the problem is entirely up to you.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://drmemory.org/docs/page_prep.html The answer is likely in there. And you can always try the *official*  support on their website. Dr. Memory has active support.